# subscribing issue after Injecting another service in service in angular rxjs

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have one service class **NetworkService** where I put all general **rest api requests like get, put, post, delete** etc and **all other services** are using this  **NetworkService**  methods for performing operation. Currently, I am **subscirbing** to the methods of **NetworkService** in all **other services**. I would like to know is there a better way of doing it so that i can do subscription in component instead in other services. For example for login I am using a method of **AuthenticationService** which is **subscribing** to the method of **NetworkService**
:

AuthenticationService method:

```
doLogin(loginData) {
 let loginParams = {
   client_id: "app",
   grant_type: "password",
   password: btoa(loginData.password),
   username: loginData.username,
 };

 this.networkService.postGetToken(loginParams).subscribe(
  (data) => {
    this.onPostGetTokenSuccess(data);
  },
  (error) => {
    this.onPostGetTokenError(error);
  }
 );
```

}

NetworkService method:

```
postGetToken(dataParam) {
   //Used only for Login
   let options = {
     headers: {
       "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
     },
   };

   let data = { params: dataParam };

   return this.http
     .post(
       this.baseurl +"svf/zsv/oauth/oauth20/token",
    data,
    options
  )
  .pipe(
    map(
      (data) => {},
      (error) => {}
    )
  );
 }
```

In **login component** I can not subscribe to the **doLogin** method of **AuthenticationService**  as in AuthenticationService  I am already subscribing to the method of **NetworkService**  and it is difficult to get result in **login component**. In login component I am doing it as follow :

```
performlogin() {
   if (!this.loginForm.valid) {
    return false;
   } else {
   this.loaderService.showLoader();

  let data = this.authenticationService.doLogin(this.loginForm.value);
   if (data["access_token"]) {
   
   } else {
   }
  }
}
```

If someone know a better way tpo do it then please share it here. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to subscribe in AuthenticationService. Just return a call to your NetworkService, and if you have any manipulations on data eg. mapping, just pipe and use other rxjs operators inside your AuthenticationService. Subscribe is always used at the end of your pipe (when you want to finally use your data) which is normally in your component. Your AuthenticationService will thus be:

```js
doLogin(loginData) : Observable<Type of data returned>{
 let loginParams = {
   client_id: "app",
   grant_type: "password",
   password: btoa(loginData.password),
   username: loginData.username,
 };

 this.networkService.postGetToken(loginParams);
}
```

Comment: i would like to call other methods of authentication service in doLogin method of athentication service  (data) => {
        this.onPostGetTokenSuccess(data);
      },
      (error) => {
        this.onPostGetTokenError(error);
      } I have update the code in question. How can i call them then?

Comment: I don't know what you're doing in onPostGetTokenSuccess, but simply move the whole subscribe block you are doing in AuthenticationService to your component,  as you have injected you AuthenticationService in the component you can easily call your onPostGetTokenSuccess like: this.authenticationService.onPostGetTokenSuccess from inside the subscribe block of the component. It's not a best practice to subscribe inside a service. And be sure to handle a way to unsubscribe as well. What you have done currently can't always work, you don't implement the async call to your service as it should be

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be one of the many use cases for Http interceptors

I recommend reading the [official documentation](https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-requests-and-responses)